# How to modify numpy array by reference in a function?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create a function which modifies a list of numpy arrays and converts them into a certain data type. I am having trouble mutating the numpy array.

Example:

```
>> a = ['1', '2']
>> convert(int, a)
>> a
a = [1, 2]
```

This code works when the function is a regular array because d[:] refers to the array and not a copy.

```
# data - data to be converted
# func - type of data 
def convert(func, *data):
    for d in data:
        d[:] = list(map(func, d))
```

This code does not work for some reason and I am puzzled as to why or how I can fix it.

```
def convert(func, *data):
    for d in data:
        d[:] = d.astype(func)
```

Alternatively:

```
def convert(func, *data):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        data[i][:] = np.array( np.zeros(len(data[i]))) # works -> sets array outside function to 0s
        data[i][...] = data[i].astype(func) # doesn't work
```

**How would one do this within numpy?**

Comment: NumPy arrays are uniformly typed; you can’t mutate the type of an array. If you mention what you are trying to achieve with this, it might be easier to solve the bigger problem.

Answer (score 0):

A string dtype array:

```
In [467]: b                                                                                    
Out[467]: array(['1', '2'], dtype='<U10')
```

make a new array with int dtype:

```
In [468]: b.astype(int)                                                                        
Out[468]: array([1, 2])
```

Assigning those values back to `b` converts them back `b's` dtype:

```
In [469]: b[:] = b.astype(int)                                                                 
In [470]: b                                                                                    
Out[470]: array(['1', '2'], dtype='<U10')
```

`astype` makes a new array; you can't change the `dtype` of an array in-place.

===

By using `*data`, you just wrap the list or array in a tuple.  Pass in `['1','2']`, and `data` becomes `(['1', '2'],), and`d`is just that list.  The`*data` and loop don't contribute anything to the problem (unless you want to convert several lists).